# Django + Jquery + Ajax + D3 won´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, d3.js

I´m currently developing a web using django framework and for the web UI i´m using d3 + jquery. The issue is that I can use separatelly all the modules of code but together they won´t work.

I have a D3 piechart on the webpage and I use jquery and jquery/ajax in order to give it usability and to change the current data shown in the graphic. The proccess is as follows:

I click on a button on the web, it creates an ajax call to the server, the DB in django return some values and convert them to json. I send those data back and try to update the D3 chart with the new set of values.

I can use some fixed data,which I have hardcode inside the d3, and it shows the piechart and change with the jquery events. If I hardcode them in the view.py and send them as the response from the get petition, the js console in the browser shows they are a json object but the D3 does´t get them. The same as if I  hardcode json_object (all are the same copied_pasted) in the jquery code but this time it works. So the data estructure is correct, the petition and the response work but the complete flow don´t.

D3 code:

```
function setupGraph() { 
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.pieChart();
        chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 60});
        var datum = data_piechart[0].values;

    chart.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
            var x = String(key);
              var y =  String(y);

              tooltip_str = '<center><b>'+x+'</b></center>' + y;
              return tooltip_str;
              });
        chart.showLabels(true);

            chart.donut(false);

    chart.showLegend(true);




        chart
            .x(function(d) { return d.label })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value });

        chart.width(450);

        chart.height(450);


            d3.select('#piechart svg')
            .datum(datum)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .attr('width',450)
            .attr('height', 450)
            .call(chart);


        });
}
```

Views.py:

```
def ajaxdata(request):

tar = request.GET['tar']
fec = request.GET['fec']
data_raw= Query (tar,fec) #This has a code of its own but
data_json= JSON.parse(data_raw)
data_json2=[{...""}]; #example of data

return HttpResponse(data_json contentype =json) #the actual syntax is the correct one, I used this one to show how i´m doing it.
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var valor = 1;
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        var date, fec;
        fec = 1;
        tar = 1;
        //I also tried the $.get option
        $.getJSON('data/', {fec: date, tar:tar}, function(data){ 
        //Tried this also var data_json = JSON.parse(data);
        data_piechart = data_json;
        setupGraph(data_piechart);
        });

    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        var date, fec;
        fec = 2;
        tar = 2;
        $.getJSON('data/', {fec: date, tar:tar}, function(data){ 
        data_piechart = data_json;
        setupGraph(data_piechart);
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone see where the problem is?

thank you for your help.

Comment: `setupGraph`  is not expecting any arguments, but you're passing one into it.

Comment: I think that using hardcoded data, your `data_piechart` becomes global scoped variable, so `setupGraph` can access it, with get request it's not possible. Try to add `data_piechart` into expected arguments in `setupGraph`. I don't know if it's correct answer because I can't see rest of your JS code, but it can be.

Comment: EDIT: Thank you GwynBleidD! sounds like a good answer. I will try asap.

Comment: i´m thinking about it and, despite the fact it might be a global variable, the setupGraph should fail as well because i´m giving it a non expected argument isnt it? And with the hardcode data the jquery works as expected updating the chart!

Comment: As I said, I can't predict behaviour of it because I can't see rest of code. Maybe something prevents it from failing, for example you have another, global `data_piechart`. Anyway, if you're passing that variable, your function should be expecting it and it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setupGraph` should expect an `data_piechart` argument.